# How to translate code with assignment in conditional to Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to translate the following code from TypeScript:

```
if (coefficient == -1 && peekToken(/^\(/, tokens)) value = "1"
    else if (variable = getToken(/^[a-zA-Z]/, tokens)) value = variable;
    else if (number = getToken(/^(\d*\.\d+)|\d+/, tokens)) value = Number(0 + number);
```

to Kotlin:

```
    if (coefficient == -1 && peekToken(Regex("""^\("""), tokens) != null) value = "1"
    else if (variable = getToken(Regex("""^[a-zA-Z]"""), tokens) != null) value = variable
    else if (number = getToken(Regex("""^(\d*\.\d+)|\d+"""), tokens) != null) value = (0 + number).toDouble()
```

The first if conditional is fine. The second one shows an error: Assignments are not expressions, and only expressions are allowed in this context. Is there an idiomatic way of rewriting that line without turning the else-if into a block of multiple statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the second line works like this:

1. get result from getToken(Regex("""^[a-zA-Z]"""), tokens)
2. check whether the result is not null (returns true false)
3. assign the value to a variable (DOES NOT RETURN TRUE/FALSE)

so basically, in your case kotlin does not know what to do, because there is an if statement that should contain a true/false, but it finds that you want to set a value to a variable there and it does not know what to do

I'm guessing you've assumed kotlin would use take the variable value (that just got changed) and use it in the `if` check, but it won't

One way to solve it would look like this:

```kotlin
var value: Any? = null
val variable = getToken(Regex("""^[a-zA-Z]"""), tokens)
val number = if (variable != null) getToken(Regex("""^(\d*\.\d+)|\d+"""), tokens) else null

if (coefficient == -1 && peekToken(Regex("""^\("""), tokens) != null) {
    value = "1"
} else if (variable != null) {
    value = variable
} else if (number != null) {
    value = (0 + number).toDouble()
}
```

or like this:

```kotlin
var value: Any? = null

val variable = getToken(Regex("""^[a-zA-Z]"""), tokens)
val number = if (variable != null) getToken(Regex("""^(\d*\.\d+)|\d+"""), tokens) else null

when {
    coefficient == -1 && peekToken(Regex("""^\("""), tokens) != null -> value = "1"
    variable != null -> value = variable
    number != null -> value = (0 + number).toDouble()
}
```

Comment: `getToken` may be not idempotent (e.g. advance some iterator). In such case these two samples are not equivalent. JS version calculates `variable` and `number` only on demand.

Comment: @STerliakov Yes, the peekToken function is an indication that the getToken function advances the parser cursor.

Comment: @JustSightseeing please update both parts of your answer to call getToken twice only if the initial call returned null. That is, `val number = getToken(Regex("""^(\d*\.\d+)|\d+"""), tokens)` should probably be `val number = if (variable != null) getToken(Regex("""^(\d*\.\d+)|\d+"""), tokens) else null`. getToken only advances the cursor if the a call to it returns something other than null.

Answer (score 3):

```
fun getOne(coefficient: Int, tokens: String): String? = ... // expression returning "1" or null
fun getAlpha(tokens: String): String? = ...                 // expression returning a String or null
fun getDouble(tokens: String): Double? = ...                // expression returning a Double or null

val value: Any? = getOne(coefficient, tokens) ?: getAlpha(tokens) ?: getDouble(tokens)
```

Comment: That one liner is hot ngl

Comment: @JustSightseeing Given I have to define three functions to make it happen, I think it's of the same complexity as your first solution. (especially if we remove the braces and newlines from the if-else-ifs from that solution)

Comment: @ekene Note that the three functions would be one-liners without braces, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions. So you indeed have a total of only four lines of code.

Comment: @lukas.j I ended up with these four lines after compressing @JustSightSeeing's first answer `val variable = getToken(Regex("""^[a-zA-Z]"""), tokens)
   val number = getToken(Regex("""^(\d*\.\d+)|\d+"""), tokens)
    val startOfParans = peekToken(Regex("""^\("""), tokens) != null
    var value: String? = (if (coefficient == -1 && startOfParans)  "1" else if (variable != null) variable else if (number != null) ("0$number").toDouble().toString() else null)
    `

Comment: @ekene Note that in this version of yours also – see STerliakov's comment on JustSightseeing's answer - might lead to a different result than the TS version. Calling _getToken_ to get a number after it has returned a valid result for [a-zA-Z] will probably advance the position of the parser, and the number will be skipped on the next round. Hence my solution which will only call _getDouble_ when _getAlpha_ returns an invalid result. It depends on the inner workings of _getToken_, but the existence of _peekToken_ is a strong indication that _getToken_ advances the cursor position of the parser.

Comment: @lukas.j Thank you for pointing that out. getToken always returns a string, and indeed advances the cursor. So if I replace the second line with `val number = variable ?: getToken(Regex("""^(\d*\.\d+)|\d+"""), tokens)` That should be okay right? Thanks once again for spotting the bug.

Comment: @ekene Yes, that should work.